# Apollo React subscribeToMore doesn't update data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm having an issue where a particular subscribeToMore function isn't correctly updating the Query data. The subscribeToMore function receives the new subscription data correctly, but it doesn't update the query.

```
updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
     if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
     let tabFields = [subscriptionData.data.fieldCreated, ...prev.tabFields];
     return Object.assign({}, prev, {
        tabFields
     });
}
```

If I console.log prev and the Object.assign function, I get:

{tabFields: Array(x)} and {tabFields: Array(x+1)} respectively. This indicates to me that the format of the returned data is correct. Yet the component is not re-rendered, such that...

```
subscribeToNew(subscribeToMore);
console.log(data.tabFields);
return renderFields(data.tabFields);
```

...does not rerender or log when the subscription occurs.

I'm totally stumped at this point. I have several other subscriptions using the same format. They work just fine. The return response matches the format of the previous data.

Comment: can you show ApolloClient options

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. Still confused as to why it worked on other subscriptions but not this one.

Comment: if you mean this trick: dataIdFromObject: o => o.id, you need to add id in the return of the mutation of adding a new subscription.

Comment: @NathanL how did you fix this?

Comment: So, how did you solve this @NathanL?
I have exactly the same problem - the solution works well everywhere except one view...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pagination?

I had a similar problem were I was fetching the last 20 messages from a chat and then trying to update through websockets. The issue is that I was making a 20-items Array => 21-items Array.

When I removed the first message and added to the end of the Array (so I kept the original length), it started to work!